# Java Win32 Service can not receive UDP packets

Tags: java, server, udp, dhcp

I've created a Java DHCP server that works fine when run from the command line but when I wrap it into a Win32 Service it doesn't seem to receive UDP Packets.

"netstat -an" does show the service listening on port 67 either way.
I know the Java process is running since it is generating a log file.

Any ideas?

Source is available here : [github/dhcp.java](https://github.com/pquiring/javaforce/blob/master/src/javaforce/service/DHCP.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the firewall blocking packets.  Odd, that it only effects services.